# cakephp console doesn't find shell dispite it's showed available

Tags: cakephp, console

I have a multi apps installation of cakephp 2.2.
I'am unable to make any shell works:

Error msg:

```
patron@serveur01linux:/cakeapps/developpement/Console$ bash cake hello
Error: Shell class HelloShell could not be found.
#0 /cakephp/2.2/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(191): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('hello')
#1 /cakephp/2.2/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#2 /cakeapps/developpement/Console/cake.php(36): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#3 {main}
```

Welcome screen:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.2.3 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : developpement
Path: /cakeapps/developpement/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

 -app: developpement
 -working: /cakeapps/developpement
 -root: /cakeapps
 -core: /cakephp/2.2/lib

Changing Paths:

Your working path should be the same as your application path to change your path use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:

[CORE] acl, api, bake, command_list, console, i18n, schema, test, testsuite, upgrade

[app] chaine, client, hello

To run an app or core command, type cake shell_name [args]
To run a plugin command, type cake Plugin.shell_name [args]
To get help on a specific command, type cake shell_name --help
```

As you can see, I work and I'm in the right folder app (/cakeapps/developpement), the core path is where the core is installed (/cakephp/2.2/lib) and the welcome screen show me my available shell.  But, I keep get this error above.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Show us the code of HelloShell.php?

Comment: Are you sure that the file `HelloShell.php` is located under `app/Console/Command`? And that the class inside is named `HelloShell` and extends `AppShell`?

Comment: Try to always call shells relative from your APP dir, so navigate into it and then call it via `Console/cake [command]`.

Answer (score 0):

As [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461173/mark) had mentioned in the comments, you should run:

```
patron@serveur01linux:/cakeapps/developpement$ bash cake hello
```

instead of:

```
patron@serveur01linux:/cakeapps/developpement/Console$ bash cake hello
```